# Question about positive Lebesgue measure set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove the following:
For a Borel set $A$ with finite positive Lebesgue measure prove that $\exists t$ s.t $\forall x \in (-t,t)$,
$A\bigcap (A-x)\neq \emptyset$

I'm trying to do this using the indicator function on A: $\chi _{A}$ and the fact that 
$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int |\chi _{A}(t-x)-\chi _{A}(t)|dt=0$ but am getting confused over how the limit going to 0 can help achieve the desired solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467589/l1-mathbbr-functions-are-continuous-in-the-metric